# Извлечение картинок из word'а

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо извлечь все картинки из docx файла. Я решил воспользоваться преобразования docx'а в zip. Есть ли какие-то способы/библиотеки для распаковки docx в zip программно? Т.е чтобы при открытии zip'а была такая раскладка папок (Вручную преобразованный docx файл в zip):[image: Вручную преобразованный docx в zip]

Просто при таком подходе:

```
string defaultPath,fileName,newFileName;
//Получаем значение переменных defaultPath,filename,newFileName и fileFormat
string path=defaultPath+fileName+".docx";
string fileInfo=File.ReadAllText(path,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
string newPath=defaultPath+newFileName+".zip";
File.WriteAllText(newPath,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

Остается только папка _rels и пустой файл [Content_Types].xml. Если это сделать невозможно, то есть ли другие способы извлечения картинок из вордовского файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**docx** это и есть сам по себе **zip** архив, програмно его можно открыть как zip архив теми средствами, которые могут открывать zip архивы.

Если вам надо програмно переименовать файл, то можно так.

```cs
string path = Path.Combine(defaultPath, fileName + ".docx");
string newPath = Path.Combine(defaultPath, fileName + ".zip");
File.Move(path, newPath);
```

К тому же, docx - это двоичный файл, а не текстовый, то есть его нельзя просто так прочитать в `string`. И если сделать ваш код рабочим с минимальными изменениями, тогда получится вот такой код.

```cs
string defaultPath,fileName,newFileName;
//Получаем значение переменных defaultPath,filename,newFileName и fileFormat
string path=defaultPath+fileName+".docx";
byte[] data=File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string newPath=defaultPath+newFileName+".zip";
File.WriteAllBytes(newPath,data);
```

Answer (score 0):

docx и есть zip.
Вам нужно не преобразование, а переименовывание.
Целую программу на C# нет необходимости писать с переливанием данных, достаточно скрипта, который переименует файлы. Или если у вас их не много, то можно вручную переименовать.